# When does normal maximal subgroup have prime index?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given finite group $G$, a normal maximal subgroup $H$, when is $[G:H]$ a prime?

If $G$ is nilpotent, then the statement is true. But I am not sure about other $G$.

Is there any counter-example (which I guess should have) s.t. the index is not a prime?

Thanks.

EDIT: Maybe I should make the question more clear. Here the normal maximal subgroup I refer to a maximal subgroup (i.e. there is no $H'$ s.t. $H< H' < G$), which also happens to be normal.

This is different from "Maximal normal subgroup", which can also be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_subgroup#Maximal_normal_subgroup), which refers to the largest normal subgroup (i.e. there is no normal subgroup $N$ s.t. $H< N < G$)

Comment: have you tried using the correspondence theorem ? (sometimes called 4th iso theorem).

Comment: @TheKindCat No, but it seems that you are right. Using the theorem and Cauchy theorem I show there is a $p$-group between $H/H$ and $G/H$, so by correspondence...

Comment: exactly, I hope this helped.

Comment: @TheKindCat Thanks. Do you want to put the hint also in an answer so I can mark this question closed?

Comment: Do you mean "normal maximal" or "maximal normal"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I mean normal maximal. That is the subgroup is normal, and also it is a maximal subgroup.

Comment: In general, $G/H$ could be any simple group. So $G=A_5$, $H=1$ is the smallest example when it is not prime.

Comment: @DerekHolt But $H=1$ is not a maximal subgroup. What I am trying to refer is a maximal subgroup which also happens to be normal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $\frac{G}{N}$ is not of prime order then $\frac{G}{N}$ has at least $1$ proper subgroup, so by the lattice correspondence theorem there is a subgroup between $N$ and $G$, contradicting the maximality of $N$.

Comment: But is the proper subgroup normal? See the remark of Qiaochu Yuan!

Comment: @NickyHekster he says $N$ is a maximal subgroup and is also normal, so t suffices to find a subgroup between $G$ and $N$ to contradict the maximality.